# In Python, how can the traceback module be used to find where an exception is generated?

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace, traceback

I'm working on a convoluted FOSS project that utilizes GTK+3. When a flow graph is generated and attempted to run it, it generates the following error:
`'Page' object has no attribute 'get_flow_graph'`

There are 30 different files that have the generic "...object has no attribute..." exception listed in the code, and there are 4 files that call the function `get_flow_graph()`.

So what I want to figure out is which of the 30 files that generate that particular error message is being executed, and preferably which of the 4 files with the function are causing the error in the first place.

I'm trying to use Python's `traceback` module to figure out where, specifically, the exception is being generated. I think I figured out the file that is calling the function that ultimately errors out, but I can't seem to get the `traceback` module to provide much more.

For example, if I wrap the function like this:

```
try:
    fg = self.page.get_flow_graph()
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

then I just get

```
  File "<redacted>", line 66, in _popen
    fg = self.page.get_flow_graph()
AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'get_flow_graph'
'Page' object has no attribute 'get_proc'
```

as the output. So I get the original exception but a new `get_proc` error that doesn't help me but is obviously associated with trying to use `traceback`.

Maybe I'm not putting the trace in the correct file/location, or maybe I'm asking too much, but how should I write it to figure out the actual stack trace for the original `AttributeError`?

Comment: "So I get the original exception but a new get_proc error that doesn't help me *but is obviously associated with trying to use traceback.*" What makes you think that? Are you sure the issue isn't that ``self.page`` fails to provide what you think it does, and therefore using it causes other failures later on? Are you aware that your ``except`` block suppresses the Exception, causing the program to limp on with possibly inconsistent state?

Answer (score 0):

Does using

```
except AttributeError as e:
  print(e.__traceback__.tb_lineno)
  print(e.__traceback__.tb_frame)
```

instead, helps you further? (really asking, not being ironic)

Comment: Good thought, but even adding that didn't generate anything. I kept getting the original error. I can confirm the file that is _causing_ the error, but I don't know why it is not receiving the "Page" instance.

Comment: I would go to the Page class and add a debug print to the `get_flow_graph()` to print maybe `__file__` to the console.

Comment: @crystalattice The exception traceback will only tell you where the concrete error came from. It will not tell you where the root issue of that error came from, e.g. why ``self.page`` has an object which does not have the expected attribute. You might be looking for an actual debugger to trace execution, not just exceptions.

Comment: Right @MisterMiyagi but still, finding the specific call that triggers the error helps in placing breakpoints to inspect variables.